# Overwriting a PNG file in Drive with a chart blob from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble using `Drive.Files.update()` to overwrite/update a series of PNG files in drive with charts from a sheet. Keeps returning `Response code: 404. Message: Not Found. (line 27, file "SaveCharts")`

Can anyone give me a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to specify a folder?

Thanks... Nick

```html
function saveChartstoGdrive(){
  //Getting chart from the current spreadsheet
  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sales Graph');
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();         
  var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length);
  var filePrefix="scrlxz";
  
  //loop through charts saving each to gdrive
  for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    
    //build each chart
    var builderChart = charts[i].modify();
    builderChart.setOption('width', 1400);
    builderChart.setOption('height', 900);
    var newChart =builderChart.build();
    chartBlobs[i]= newChart.getAs('image/png');
    
    //make sure we have the correct file and prepare for saving
    var fileName = filePrefix+[i]+".png";
    var fileId = DriveApp.searchFiles(title = fileName);
    //var fileId = DriveApp.searchFiles(name = fileName);
    // var fileTyper = {title: fileName, mimeType: 'image/png'};
    var contentBlob = chartBlobs[i];
    
    //save file to ggdrive
    var myVar = Drive.Files.update({mimeType: 'image/png'}, fileId, contentBlob);
    
    // other ideas i've tried
    // var myVar = Drive.Files.update(fileTyper, fileId, contentBlob);
    // updateFileContent(fileId, contentBlob, function(response) {console.log(response);})                      
    // var myVar = Drive.Files.update(fileId, contentBlob);
  }         
}
```

Comment: In your script, there are errors at the query of ``DriveApp.searchFiles()`` and the way to retrieve fileId. Before modifying your script, I would like to ask you about your situation. File with ``fielName`` of ``var fileName = filePrefix+[i]+".png";`` is only one in your Google Drive?

Comment: yes.. they are unique file names... Do I need an index on the search result?... like: `DriveApp.searchFiles(name = fileName)[0]`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- About `DriveApp.searchFiles(title = fileName)`, in this script, no error occurs. But when the it tries to retrieve the values using `next()`, an error occurs. And `title = fileName` is not used as the search query.
- Value retrieved by `DriveApp.searchFiles(title = fileName)` is FileIterator.

By above points, it is considered that such error occurs. In order to remove this error, please modify as follows.

From :

```
var fileId = DriveApp.searchFiles(title = fileName);
```

To :

```
var fileId = DriveApp.searchFiles("title='" + fileName + "'").next().getId();
```

or

You can also use `getFilesByName()` using `fileName`.

```
var fileId = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next().getId();
```

#### Note :

In this modification, it supposes the following points.

- Chart builder works.
- File with `fielName` of `var fileName = filePrefix+[i]+".png"` is only one in your Google Drive.
- At Google Drive, files are managed by the file ID. So the files with the same filename can be existing, because the file IDs are different. When `searchFiles()` and `getFilesByName()` are used for retrieving files, if there are several files with the same filename in Google Drive, it is required to prepare the script for processing it. So at first, I had asked about the number of files with the filename.

#### References :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)
- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)
- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Tanaike that worked perfectly. Great answer.

Comment: @Nick Ritar I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.